# Which video format is best for all type of browsers?

Tags: django

Iam working in a django application with video uploading in server. I need to stream a video in browser on a button click. Iam using the below code,

```
<video style="background-color: #efefef;" controls>
            <source src="{{ url }}" type='video/mp4'>
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video>
```

where the {{url}} comes from views.py,

The code is ,

```
 def get(self, request):             
        video_name = 'demo.mp4'  
        video_url = settings.MEDIA_URL + video_name    
        if video_url:   
        return render(request, "videostream.html", {"url": video_url})
```

Can anyone please suggest the video format which supports for all the browsers such as safari, firefox, chrome, internet explorer etc.?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to MDN, **mp4** has the best support among all browsers